# Powershell Script for IIS Website (SMTP Relay)

Tags: powershell, iis, azure, reboot

I need to write a piece of script for adjusting the size of a Microsoft Azure Virtual Machine (VM). This is all well and good, and I have the script written and functioning.

However,

Any time the scheduled script runs to make a change it restarts the VM. The problem I have is, that when the server restarts the IIS Website for the SMTP relay does not restart.

Can someone please advise me on the PowerShell script I need to include at the bottom of my script to ensure this website restarts when the server reboots after the update?

Kind Regards,
And thanks in advance.

AG

Comment: *" IIS Website for the SMTP relay does not restart."* - that doesn't make sense...do you mean that the SMTP service doesn't start?

Comment: Yes I understand what you mean. 

Although it is not a service. It is under IIS, as a default website, called 'SMTP Virtual Server #1'

Comment: Have you checked in `Control Panel -> Administration -> Services` to see if the SMTP service is configured to automatically start?

Comment: I have just checked this, it is set to manual. And is set to started.

I think you may have hit the nail right on the head @Kev.

How do I mark this as answered?

Comment: Cool...I've created an answer for you to mark as answered :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked in `Control Panel -> Administration -> Services` to see if the SMTP service is configured to automatically start?

Make sure the *"Startup type"* dropdown is set to `Automatic`:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is a PowerShell cmdlet to restart a Virtual SMTP Server:

```
$SMTP=[adsi]"IIS://localhost/SMTPSVC/1"
$SMTP.ServerState = 2
$SMTP.SetInfo()
```

I hope this helps!

Mitch Garvis, MCSE:PC
www.garvis.ca